# Drill-down feature is at OLAP or BI layer?

Tags: business-intelligence, olap, drilldown

Drill-down, by definition, requires the use of hierarchical data where values are grouped into levels. ([reference](https://www.dundas.com/resources/blogs/introduction-to-business-intelligence/drilling-into-the-differences-between-drill-down-drill-through))

My understanding of drill-down feature is provided by OLAP engine (e.g. Clickhouse, Apache Druid, Apache Pinot etc) and not BI/Visualisation tool (e.g. Tableau, Superset, Grafana etc). However from this presentation slides *Seeing Is Believing: Popular BI Tools for ClickHouse* ([link](https://presentations.clickhouse.com/meetup52/bi.pdf)), it said Grafana supports interactive drill-down on data but not Superset.

My questions:

1. Drill-down feature is at OLAP or BI layer?
2. Does drill-down feature require pre-computed dimensional
   aggregations?
3. How dimensions that can be drilled down are identified? Manually or automatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Drill-down feature is at OLAP or BI layer?
```

Not sure what you mean by the both... but you might check the response to the third question.

```
Does drill-down feature requires pre-computed dimensional aggregations?
```

Not necessarily. For example, [icCube](https://www.icCube.com) is computing the aggregated values on-the-fly while processing a query; whether it is related to a drilldown or not does not matter at all.

```
How dimensions that can be drilled down are identified? Manually or automatically?
```

The visualization tools should somehow know that a dimension exists and that the members of that dimension (e.g., a country, a year) have some children (e.g., cities, quarters) and have a way to query those children. This is automatic for client tool (e.g., Excel, Tableau) connecting for example to icCube, SSAS, ... Those tools are able to *discover* the dimensions structure first.